# Escaping the prison - finding the shortest way

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have given an assignment where I have to escape a labyrinth. The goal is to find the shortest way. I have done some research and there seem to be two strategies to solve the problem: the [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), where the first starts at the root (Starting point in maze) and explores as far as possible along each branch before backtracking and the second begins at a root node and inspects all the neighboring nodes. Then for each of those neighbor nodes in turn, it inspects their neighbor nodes which were unvisited, and so on.

I have implemented both algorithms (non-recursive implementations) that will go on until they find the end:

```
/**
 * A non-recursive implementation of DFS
 * @param maze
 */
void solveUsingDepthFirst(IMaze maze) {
    Stack<IMazePosition> candidates = new Stack<IMazePosition>();
    //insert start position
    candidates.push(maze.getStartPosition());

    IMazePosition currentPosition;
    IMazePosition nextPosition;
    while (!candidates.empty()) {
        currentPosition = candidates.pop();

        if (maze.isMazeSolved(currentPosition)) break;

        //mark the current position
        maze.markPosition(currentPosition, maze.getPathMark());
      // maze.printMaze();
        // Check for possible ways to go
        nextPosition = currentPosition.north();
        if (maze.canMove(nextPosition)) candidates.push(nextPosition);
        nextPosition = currentPosition.east();
        if (maze.canMove(nextPosition)) candidates.push(nextPosition);
        nextPosition = currentPosition.south();
        if (maze.canMove(nextPosition)) candidates.push(nextPosition);
        nextPosition = currentPosition.west();
        if (maze.canMove(nextPosition)) candidates.push(nextPosition);
    }

    System.out.println(!candidates.empty() ? "Done" : "Sorry, could not do it");
    maze.printMaze();
}

/**
 * A non-recursive implementation of BFS
 * @param maze
 */
void solveUsingBreadthFirst(IMaze maze) {
    LinkedList<IMazePosition> candidates = new LinkedList<IMazePosition>();
    //insert start position
    candidates.add(maze.getStartPosition());

    IMazePosition currentPosition;
    IMazePosition nextPosition;
    while (!candidates.isEmpty()) {
        currentPosition = candidates.removeFirst();

        if (maze.isMazeSolved(currentPosition)) break;

        //markPosition the current position
        maze.markPosition(currentPosition, maze.getPathMark());
     //   maze.printMaze();

        // Check for possible ways to go
        nextPosition = currentPosition.north();
        if (maze.canMove(nextPosition)) candidates.add(nextPosition);
        nextPosition = currentPosition.east();
        if (maze.canMove(nextPosition)) candidates.add(nextPosition);
        nextPosition = currentPosition.south();
        if (maze.canMove(nextPosition)) candidates.add(nextPosition);
        nextPosition = currentPosition.west();
        if (maze.canMove(nextPosition)) candidates.add(nextPosition);
    }

    System.out.println(!candidates.isEmpty() ? "Done" : "Sorry, could not do it");
    maze.printMaze();
}
```

The map (or the maze) is represented as `char[][]`. The MazePosition is a representation of coordinates:

```
public MazePosition(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Now with that code, I have all the possible paths from start to end that I was able to find until I found the end for the first time - is it fair to assume that the shortest path is amongst them? 
Given that I have the possible paths, how would I go with finding the shortest? And, is the code for path generation any good at all? Can I optimize any of the routines I already have.

Also, as far as I know, there are no "holes" in the maze, which means I can always stick to the wall.

Comment: Questions asking to improve and critique functioning code are more suitable at [codereview.se].

Comment: a breadth first search will advance all positions by one... so the first one to solve the maze is the shortest, right?

Comment: A BFS will always give you the optimal solution, but a DFS will not. Since each square is visited at most one time, keep track of the square from which you came and just backtrack from the end back to the beginning.

Comment: @Blender, wouldn't it be the other way around by the argument just given by djb?

Comment: @Heuster: You're right, I flipped them around.

Comment: I can't see any pros/cons of preferring DFS to BFS and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

if you have all possible paths, I'm willing to bet the shortest is among them.

As Blender mentioned, in a breadth first search the first solution discovered will be amongst the set of optimal solutions (shortest paths).

How to find out how long a path a candidate is? Add a pathLength field to your `MazePosition` class, increment it each time you add a candidate position. When you reach daylight that field will tell you how many steps you've come.

What about mazes without an exit? Perhaps you should keep track of where you have been.

In order to answer questions about "goodness" and "optimization" we need to know what constraints you are working under. How slow is too slow? How big are these mazes? **Premature optimization is the root of all evil.**

Answer (score 1):

Depth first is unlikely to find the shortest route unless there are only a small number of possible routes (and you wouldn't be able to confirm it was the shortest route).

Breadth first will always find "a" shortest route first, assuming you are incrementing the same distance at each node at every step (there may be multiple routes of equal length).

If you ever reach an iteration with no more steps possible then the maze is insoluble.

Probably the simplest way to record the actual route is to 'mark' each position with distance-so-far, then when you reach the exit you can trace the route in reverse (from finish to start) by repeatedly stepping to a neighbouring position with a smaller distance-so-far recorded until you get back to the start (while, of course, recording the route).

Depending on the dimensionality of the maze, if you already know where the exit is, you may be able to reduce the number of steps required to find the route by doing breadth first from both the starting and finishing points until the searches coincide (if that isn't considered to be "cheating").